# GPIO works on PI Model B but does not work on PI 3 Model B

Tags: gpio, pi-3, java, pi4j, pi-b

Something very unusual is happening here.

I wrote a program in Java (using Pi4J) to blink a led (to debug the problem).

```
testPin = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01,"TEST",PinState.HIGH);
testPin.blink(100);
```

If I insert microSD card on an old PI Model B, it works.

If I insert microSD card on a brand new PI 3 Model B, it does not.

It is not only the same program. It is the same everything! Both cases I run the same microSD card, with the same environment. Just changing the hardware.

I thought that the PI 3 Model B was ruined. But, just in case, I decided to test it in Python. **IT WORKS!** I mean, it works on both computers.

This is the Python program:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO        
import time                               
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)   
GPIO.setwarnings(False)          
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)       
while(1):                                   
    print("ON\n")          
    GPIO.output(12, 1)               
    time.sleep(1)                        
    print("OFF\n")      
    GPIO.output(12, 0)               
    time.sleep(1)
```

It is driving me crazy.
It does not make any sense.

Environment:

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Obs: I use this Java version to have JavaFX

```
Linux raspberrypi1 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

pi4j version 0.0.5
```

Any clue?
Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

It was the Pi4J version.
I migrated to the latest version (1.1) and it worked.

Tks!